# Want to run wordpress in a subdirectory and keep my main site separate in the root

Tags: wordpress

I have an eCommerce website in the root directory and want to move my blog to a subdirectory. I successfully made the move from another domain to this one but when I attempt to go to the blog home page it re-directs to my eCommerce site's home page.

The eCommerce site - http://www.heavytshirt.com
The blog location - `http://www.heavytshirt.com/blog`

The .htaccess file in the blog directory looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

And the .htaccess file in the root directory looks like this:

```
DirectoryIndex /mm5/merchant.mvc?Screen=SFNT

RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^mm5/admin.mvc? - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-s
RewriteRule ^product/([^/.]+).html$ /mm5/merchant.mvc?Screen=PROD&Product_code=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-s
RewriteRule ^category/([^/.]+).html$ /mm5/merchant.mvc?Screen=CTGY&Category_code=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-s
RewriteRule ^product/([^/]+)/([^/.]+).html$ /mm5/merchant.mvc?Screen=PROD&Category_code=$1&Product_code=$2 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-s
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+).html$ /mm5/merchant.mvc?Screen=$1 [L]

### End - Inserted by Miva Merchant

Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{http_host} ^heavytshirt.com [nc]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.heavytshirt.com/$1 [r=301,nc]


# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Currently I am able to type in a subsequent sub directory and get to a post - Like:
`http://www.heavytshirt.com/blog/category/summershirts/`

What can I do to make the blog home page come up when someone types in `http://www.heavytshirt.com/blog`  
And not affect the main site at `www.heavytshirt.com`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not looking into your apache configuration, since I believe it can easily be configured within WordPress.

Go into your WordPress administration panel, and move to `Settings / General Settings`.

Now change the values of [`WordPress Address (URL)`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory) and [`Site Address (URL)`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory) accordingly. Read [this WordPress Codex article](http://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory) for more details.

Comment: Thing is, I don't want to edit my primary .htaccess because it controls how my eCommerce site works and I need it not to be interrupted. I went ahead and tried some of the other things like moving a copy of index.php to the root directory and made the edits as instructed and now I can't get to any of the pages of my blog, even if I type in the url all the way in. I changed everything back to the way it was before and now nothing works at all. Now I am in trouble.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is because you have set

```
DirectoryIndex /mm5/merchant.mvc?Screen=SFNT
```

Because /blog/ is a directory and the rules you have set are matching that as the directory index for /blog/ (because the directory actually exists).

You will have to combine the two Rewrite Directives to get the desired result (you don't need RewriteEngine On in there twice).

Probably better that you start from scratch testing line by line to make sure you get the desired result.

I can't test this, but you get the idea:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks

RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^mm5/admin.mvc? - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-s
RewriteRule ^product/([^/.]+).html$ /mm5/merchant.mvc?Screen=PROD&Product_code=$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-s
RewriteRule ^category/([^/.]+).html$ /mm5/merchant.mvc?Screen=CTGY&Category_code=$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-s
RewriteRule ^product/([^/]+)/([^/.]+).html$ /mm5/merchant.mvc?Screen=PROD&Category_code=$1&Product_code=$2 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-s
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+).html$ /mm5/merchant.mvc?Screen=$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{http_host} ^heavytshirt.com [nc]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.heavytshirt.com/$1 [r=301,nc]

RewriteBase /blog/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
```